# Sort function in javascript when condition is equal

Tags: javascript

I want to sort the the strings in a file according to second word first and if they are equal then consider the first word. On line 17 how can i add condition to check if word is same and then sort it according to first word.

Here is my code : https://jsfiddle.net/am03uf7e/

```
var finalLine=[];
function testing() {
    var logFileSize = 5;
    var logLines = ["a1 9 2 3 1", "g1 act car", "z04 4 7", "ab1 off  key dog", "a8 act zoo" ];
  var newLinesw=[];
  var newLinesn=[];
  var wordsarray=[];
  for(var i=0; i< logFileSize; i++) {
        var words = logLines[i].split(" ");
    if(isNaN(words[1]) )
        newLinesw.push(logLines[i]);
    else 
      newLinesn.push(logLines[i]);
    }
  newLinesw.sort(function(a,b){return a.split(" ")[1].localeCompare(b.split(" ")[1]); });

  //To Do : apply condition for the same second word and sort by 1 word. 
  for(i=0;i<newLinesw.length;i++){
    wordsarray.push(newLinesw[i].split(" ")[1]);
  }

  newLinesn.sort(function(a,b){return a.split(" ")[0].localeCompare(b.split(" ")[0]); });
   finalLine = newLinesw.concat(newLinesn);
   return finalLine;

}
document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML = testing();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `||` to test against the first words if the initial comparison comes out to `0`:

```
return a.split(" ")[1].localeCompare(b.split(" ")[1]) || a.split(" ")[0].localeCompare(b.split(" ")[0]);
```

But this is pretty WET and hard to read. Better to come up with variables for each word:

```
newLinesw.sort(function(a, b) {
  const [a0, a1] = a.split(" ");
  const [b0, b1] = b.split(" ");
  return a1.localeCompare(b1) || a0.localeCompare(b0);
});
```